# SQL Server: Return NULL: SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%'

Tags: sql-server, null, return-value, isnull

Hello and thank you in advance for helping out a noob. I tried a few different search and could not find an example where `%` is the alternate value so I apologize if this is a duplicate thread.

My data looks like this

Table Name = `stored_item`

```
Item  |  Location |  Hu  
---------------------------
K134  |  LOC01    |  LP1  
K125  |  LOC02    |  LP2  
K345  |  LOC03    |  
K939  |  LOC05    |  LP5
K235  |  LOC05    |  LP5
```

I need to query the table and need to return results based on where clause on the `Hu` column.

Code looks like this: Where x can be any value for Hu or % to indicate search for all values (including null values)

```
DECLARE @hu nvarchar(15)
    SET @hu = 'X'

SELECT Item, Hu
FROM stored_item
WHERE Hu LIKE @hu
```

If X = 'LP5' then results should look like this:

```
Item  |  Location |  Hu  
---------------------------
K939  |  LOC05    |  LP5
K235  |  LOC05    |  LP5
```

IF X = '%' Then results should look like this:

```
Item  |  Location |  Hu  
---------------------------
K134  |  LOC01    |  LP1  
K125  |  LOC02    |  LP2  
K345  |  LOC03    |  
K939  |  LOC05    |  LP5
K235  |  LOC05    |  LP5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @hu nvarchar(15)
SET @hu = 'X'

SELECT  Item, Hu
FROM    stored_item
WHERE   @hu = '%' OR Hu LIKE @hu
```

In this case if your parameter is `%` the condition `@hu = '%'` will cause `WHERE` condition to be ignored, otherwise the second part of the condition will be used

Comment: That fixed it right up! If you don't mind, could provide a little more info on why that works, I know I'm fairly new to SQL but that @hu = % part has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the COALESCE function on the column you would like to search. This will convert NULL values to a value of your choosing. Because a non-NULL value will match '%', using this technique will return NULL rows as well. 
This way you can use the value of @hu with regular wildcards (such as %) allowed with LIKE. If you only want to select the rows that start with LP, and not the NULL row, for instance, you can set @hu to 'LP%'.

```
DECLARE @hu nvarchar(15)
SET @hu = '%'

SELECT  Item, Hu
FROM    stored_item
--The value you use in Coalesce should never exist in the table. This can be 
--accomplished by using a string that is longer than the Hu column could hold. 
--In my case, the Hu column is a VARCHAR(3), so 4 positions should be enough.
WHERE   COALESCE(Hu, 'XXXX') LIKE @hu
```

I used this test data for this query:

```
CREATE TABLE stored_item
([Item] varchar(4), [Location] varchar(5), [Hu] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO stored_item
([Item], [Location], [Hu])
VALUES
('K134', 'LOC01', 'LP1'),
('K125', 'LOC02', 'LP2'),
('K345', 'LOC03', NULL),
('K939', 'LOC05', 'LP5'),
('K235', 'LOC05', 'LP5')
;
```

More information on the COALESCE function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx